# Detect if iPhone or iPad on iOS WKWebView using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, wkwebview

How to detect if I'm running on iPhone or iPad using Javascript.
I have an app that uses WKWebView in order to show web content and need to distinguish which is being used.

SideNote: I've tested the solution using `navigator.UserAgent`, but in that case both are the SAME:
**`navigator.UserAgent`:**

> mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 7_0_2 like mac os x) applewebkit/537.51.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/7.0 mobile/11a501 safari/9537.53

Any other way to accomplish that?